# Why my css not affective while printing

Tags: css, xhtml

I am using external css in xhtml for printing my page. In browser it is showing the right output but while printing the css does not effect. Why? Please help.

Comment: Here is a link on how to set up a print stylesheet: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to specify the print styles, for example:

```
@media print {
...
}
```

The stylesheet default is screen, so it does not apply to printers.

**References**

- [media » Learn CSS3 | Cheat Sheet | CSS Tutorial | Selectors | Properties](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-media)
- [Create a Customized Print Stylesheet in Minutes — SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-customized-print-stylesheet-in-minutes/)